# Em, размеры отступов и элементов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Дан макет шириной `2880px`, верстаю на мониторе шириной `1024px`. Не совсем понимаю, как переносить размеры с макета в верстку.

Например, дан текстовый блок с размером шрифта на макете `32px` и отступом слева `64px` и снизу `128px`.

Какие размеры использовать при верстке на мониторе `1024px` (в em)?

Comment: так а что за макет на 2880px ? обычно максимум размер контента может быть 1920px. а то, что находится вне центральной области макета, это обычно фон сайта.

Comment: размер фоновой (боковой) части макета вычислять не нужно

Comment: http://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/8/18/39b9c512338c79258dbf243b1a6874b1-full.jpg

Comment: в инете макет нашел, для портфолио)

Comment: @word, device pixel ratio.

Comment: @Qwertiy, not pixel ratio

Comment: @word, 2880 = 1440 на соответствующем [устройстве](https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/specs/) - точнее, там 2732 * 2048.

Comment: @Qwerti, так обычно макет psd рисуется без pixel ratio, в оригинальных размерах

Comment: @word, ну это уж кто как нарисует. Особенно если дизайнер делал в духе скриншот вот отсюда, а потом нарисовать те блоки, которые нужны с нужным содержимым и удалить скриншот.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ:
Если заказчик хочет адаптивный сайт и дал вам макет только под большой монитор, то у вас есть несколько вариантов:

1) Попросить у него как минимум еще два макета (для мобильного и маленького экрана), из которых будет ясно, какой размер шрифта вам нужен.

2) Если макетов больше вам не дадут, то нужно добиться того, чтобы сайт соответствовал макету на 2880px, а на 1024px сделать по своему внутреннему ощущению прекрасного. Все-равно к вам не смогут докопаться с несоответствием макету.

А вот если вам не нужен адаптивный сайт, то смело делайте ширину у body 2880px и верстайте по макету, не забыв при этом установить вьюпорт.

П.С. заказчики, заставляющие пересчитывать хоть что-нибудь с их макетов, будь то колонки или шрифты обычно получают не самые качественные результаты)